# Conditional reference is not working VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, conditional-compilation

I need to reference a 3rd party DLLs.
They exist in 2 version: 6.3 and 6.4.
So what im about to do ? In Solution Configuration manager, I added 4 new active solution configurations:
6.3-Release
6.3-Debug
6.4-Release
6.4-Debug

According to these version, I would like to change my references.
I have a folder: external\6.4\REFERENCED DLLS LOCATED
And additional folder: external\6.3\REFERENCED DLLS LOCATED

The dll names are the same, but the folders are different.. 
What is my goal ?
When i set build configuration to be: 6.4-Release i want the references DLLs to be from external\6.4.. and when set build configuration to be 6.3-Release from external\6.3..

Why is that ? Since they have new API Properties (that i need) that available only in the new DLLs.

So later on in my code, I can make custom code in certain places according to build configuration and it will compile.

So what i've done is:
1. Added 4 new build configuration
2. Open the .csproj in notepad++ and editing as following:
3. Between < /PropertyGroup > and < ItemGroup > I added the following:

```
<Choose>
<When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '6.4-Release'">
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="IPAddressControlLib.dll">
        <HintPath>..\external\IPAddressControlLib.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
</When>
</Choose>
```

What i expect ? When i load the solution and select build configuration  6.4-Release, i will see this dll in the references dlls list, And when i select something else - I wont see it.

But this never happens, i never see the dll "IPAddressControlLib" in my reference list (in gui inside visual studio).

What im doing wrong ? thanks.

Comment: Forgetting the GUI side, does it actually *build* properly? Note that your HintPath doesn't include 6.4, which seems odd.

Comment: This is a little POC i did, I would like to add a certain reference when i set 6.4-Release and not reference it on any other case

Comment: That doesn't actually address either the question I raised or the issue with your sample (which doesn't match your description)...

Comment: the references dll "IPAddressControlLib" does exist in the proper place, I would like to add him as reference when i set the build to 6.4-Release, The project is built fine.

Comment: I guess you made a point, dont look at the gui. What i just did - I deleted all dll files from build path, and set in the <Choose> of the dll - <Private>True</Private> - the dll was copied to output, and when i set <Private>False</Private> it was not

Comment: This means that when i refer dlls by Choice they will not appear in GUI ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the `Private` part means at all, but that sounds like a different question, really. You still haven't addressed why your sample is just to `..\external\IPAddressControlLib.dll` rather than `..\external\6.4\IPAddressControlLib.dll` as per your description. Have you checked that the right version is being copied?

Comment: (You really don't need a `Choose`, by the way - you can just put a `Condition = ...` on the `Reference` element.)

Comment: I deleted the question, and then un-deleted, I will post a solution, There was a bug in visual studio, Once you rename existing configuration. in the dropdown menu it will be under the new name, but when you define a condition in a reference, it must be the old name. and this confuses, meaning that if i renamed the original "Debug" to "6.3-Debug", in the .csproj file, i still need to set "Debug" in the If Condition and not "6.3-Debug" as i expected

Comment: And you were right, i dont need <Choice> I Just do:  <Reference Include="Entities.Metadata" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == '6.4-Debug' OR '$(Configuration)' == '6.4-Release'">